# has_category not working correctly

Tags: categories

On my [website](http://alexander-pastor.de) I want to mark featured articles with a star icon, which works by checking if a post has the category "Featured". However, it somehow always seems to return true for backdated articles, which is really strange. (Everything below Computers -> Programming Best Practices, for instance is wrongly marked as featured!). Making it even more awkward, it is not even called for these backdated articles and strange enough twice for each featured article.

Here's my code from functions.php:

```
function showPosts($number, $category="", $description = false, $disambiguation = null, $featured = false, $collapsible = true, $thumbnail = false, $languageFlag = true)
{
    global $post;

            $args = array(
              'numberposts'       =>   $number,
              'category_name'     =>   $category
            );

    $myposts = get_posts($args); 

    if( $myposts )
    {   
        // hidden posts due to language setting
        $hiddenPosts = 0;

        // get cookie data (prefered language(s))
        if(isset($_COOKIE["post-data"])) :
            $allowedLanguages = get_tangboshi_cookies();
        else:
            $allowedLanguages = array();
        endif;

        // if language setting has not been set, allow all
        // not very elegant to have all the stuff in a single array (post-data), with multiple arrays one could use array.empty();

        if( !(in_array("posts-english", $allowedLanguages) || in_array("posts-german", $allowedLanguages)) ) :
            array_push($allowedLanguages, "posts-english");
            array_push($allowedLanguages, "posts-german");
        endif;

        foreach( $myposts as $post ) 
        {
            setup_postdata($post);

            $id = convertText(get_the_title())."-".$disambiguation;
            $postID = get_the_ID();

            $status = get_post_meta($postID, "status", true);

            switch ($status)
            {
                case "": $statusText = ""; break;
                default: $statusText = '<span class="caption-draft"> - '.$status.'</span>'; break;
            }

            if ( $featured ) : 
                $id .= "-featured";
            endif;

            // same problem with has_category('Featured')
            if ( in_category('Featured') )
            {
                // every featured article mentioned twice; BUG!!
                // backdated always get start...
                $icon = 'star';
            }


            // get language of current post
            $language = get_post_meta($postID, "language", true);

            // if language not mentioned, default is English
            if ( !$language )
            {
                $language = "english";
            }

            // filter out posts with wrong language

            if ( in_array("posts-".$language, $allowedLanguages) )
            {
                $isAllowedLanguage = true;
            }
            else
            {
                $isAllowedLanguage = false;
            }

            if($languageFlag):
                switch($language):              
                    case "english": $flagicon = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-squared flag-icon-us"></span> ';break;
                    case "german":  $flagicon = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-squared flag-icon-de"></span> ';break;
                    case "french":  $flagicon = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-squared flag-icon-fr"></span> ';break;
                    case "chinese": $flagicon = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-squared flag-icon-cn"></span> ';break;
                    default:        throw("Uncaught exception: undefined post language.");
                endswitch;

                $languageFlagText = $flagicon;
            endif;

            if( $collapsible && $isAllowedLanguage )
            {
                $postArgs = array(
                    "id"            =>  $id,
                    "caption"       =>  $languageFlagText.get_the_title().$statusText,
                    "icon"          =>  $icon,
                    "initialState"  =>  "out",
                    "function"      =>  "showPostDescription",
                    "args"          =>  $thumbnail,
                    "style"         =>  "modern-post"
                );

                $ret .= call_user_func_array("createPanelWidget", $postArgs);
            }
            elseif ( !$collapsible )
            {
                $ret.= "<p>Non-collapsible detected. Unimplemented. Please set collapsible to true.</p>";
            }
            else
            {
                $hiddenPosts++;
            }


            the_post();
        }

        wp_reset_query();
    }

    if($hiddenPosts > 0) : $ret.= "<p>Hidden posts due to your language setting: ".$hiddenPosts.".</p>"; endif;

    return $ret;
}

function createPanelWidget($id, $caption, $icon, $initialState, $function = "noop", $args = null, $functionHandlesArray = false, $style = 'modern', $nestedLevel = 1)
{
    if( $function == "createPanelWidget" )
    {
        $newLevel = $nestedLevel + 1;
        $args["nestedLevel"] = $newLevel;
    }

    if ( is_array($args) && !$functionHandlesArray )
    {
        $tmp = call_user_func_array($function, $args); 
    }
    else
    {
        $tmp = call_user_func($function, $args);
    }

    // prevent empty panels from being created
    if(!isset($tmp)) : return; endif;

    $ret .= '
        <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-level-'.$nestedLevel.'" id="'.$id.'-panel">
                <div class="panel-heading panel-'.$style.'">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#'.$id.'">
                        <div class="panel-caption-wrapper">
                            <div class="panel-caption">
                                <p>
                                    ';
                                    if(isset($icon))
                                    {
                                        $ret .= '<span class="fa fa-'.$icon.'"></span>';
                                    }
    $ret .= '
                                    '.$caption.'
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-toggle-icon">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                    <span class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></span>
                                    <span class="toggle-icon"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>      
                </div>
                <div id="'.$id.'" class="panel-collapse collapse '.$initialState.'">
                    <div class="panel-body panel-'.$style.'">';
                            $ret .= $tmp;
    $ret .=  '
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    '; 

    return $ret; 
}
```

**EDIT:**

In my `index.php` I call `"createMainPanel(...)"`, `showPosts(...)` is called as a callback of call_userf_func_array with `panelAllPostsParams(...)`:

```
function createMainPanel()
{
    $catsArgs = array(
        'parent'        =>  0,
        'orderby'       =>  'count',
        'order'         =>  'DESC',
        'hide_empty'    =>  true,
        'exclude'       =>  array(12) // 12 is Featured
    );

    $cats = get_categories($catsArgs);

    //var_dump($cats);

    $ret .= '<div id="primary" class="content-area">';
    $ret .= '<main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">';

    //$ret .= '<div class="warning">Since Wed. 28 Dec, 2016 23:30 UTC+1 this page is under maintenance. Expect a lot of stuff to return in the next few days.</div>';

    $ret .= addLoadingIcon(500, 400);

    $ret .= "<ul class='nav nav-tabs' id='main-panel-cats'>";


    foreach( $cats as $index => $cat )
    {
        $catName    =   $cat->cat_name;
        $catRef     =   convertText($catName);

        if( $index == 0 ){ $active = " active "; }
        else{ $active = ""; }
        $icon = "fa fa-".getIcon($catName);

        $ret .= "<li class='".$active."'><a href='#".$catRef."' data-toggle='tab'><span class='".$icon."'></span> ".$catName."</a></li>";   
    }

    $ret .= "</ul>";

    $ret .= '<div class="tab-content">';

    foreach( $cats as $cat )
    {
        static $counter = 0;

        $description    =   category_description($cat);
        $catName        =   $cat->cat_name;

        //set first tab to active tab, if there's stuff in localstorage javascript will change this later
        if( !$counter ){ $active = " active "; }
        else{ $active = ""; }

        $icon = "fa fa-".getIcon($catName);

        $catRef = convertText($catName);

        $ret    .= '<div id="'.$catRef.'" class="tab-pane'.$active.'">';
        $ret    .= '<div class="row">';
        $ret    .= '<div class="col-md-12">';

        $panelHeadlineParams = array(
            'id'                =>      'desc-'.$catRef, 
            'caption'           =>      'What can I expect from <span class="'.$icon.'"></span> '.$catName.' articles?', 
            'icon'              =>      'info-circle', 
            'initialState'      =>      'out', 
            'function'          =>      'showString', 
            'args'              =>      $description
        );

        $panelFeaturedParams = array(
            'id'                =>      'featured-'.$catRef, 
            'caption'           =>      'Featured articles in <span class="'.$icon.'"></span> '.$catName, 
            'icon'              =>      'star', 
            'initialState'      =>      'out', 
            'function'          =>      'showPosts', 
            'args'              =>      array(
                'number'            =>      null, 
                'category'          =>      strtoupper($catRef),
                'description'       =>      false,
                'disambiguation'    =>      $catRef,
                'featured'          =>      true
            )
        );

        $panelAllPostsParams = array(
            'id'                =>      'posts-'.$catRef, 
            'caption'           =>      'All posts about <span class="'.$icon.'"></span> '.$catName, 
            'icon'              =>      'pencil', 
            'initialState'      =>      'in', 
            'function'          =>      'showPosts', 
            'args'              =>      array(
                'number'            =>      null, 
                'category'          =>      strtoupper($catRef),
                'description'       =>      true,
                'disambiguation'    =>      $catRef
            )
        );

        $ret .= call_user_func_array("createPanelWidget", $panelHeadlineParams);
        $ret .= call_user_func_array("createPanelWidget", $panelFeaturedParams);
        $ret .= call_user_func_array("createPanelWidget", $panelAllPostsParams);

        $ret    .= '</div><!-- col -->';
        $ret    .= '</div><!-- row -->';
        $ret    .= '</div><!-- tab-pane -->';

        $counter++;
    }


    $ret .= '</div> <!-- tab-content -->';
    $ret .= '</main>';
    $ret .= '</div> <!-- #primary -->';

    echo $ret;
}
```

Comment: For future questions, I would suggest reducing your code to the absolute minimum reproducible example. This drives more answers as such an amount of code normally drives answerers away.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you do not reset the icon variable after each iteration of the loop, therefor once it gets to be a "star" it will always remain.

Comment: I don't understand why this has been downvoted, it is in fact the correct answer to my problem.

Comment: some people just don't like short answers, maybe whoever downvoted felt I should have added an example how to do it right..... One of the important things about contributing to the stackexchange sites is not to take this kind of downvotes personally as sometime (don't think that in this case) they might be right. (but IMO it is a bad thing to downvote an answer without saying why, if someone thinks an answer can be improved he should say how)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're not using `get_posts` correctly (looks like you're mixing `WP_Query` methods such as `the_post` in with results from `get_posts`). Please read on the differences between `WP_Query` and `get_posts`, for example [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

Have you tried passing the current post ID into `in_category`?

```
if ( in_category('Featured', $post->ID) )
```

Comment: Yes, I tried adding `$post->ID` . Did not make any difference (it should not also according to the codex).

Comment: You are right about `the_post()`! It is completely redundant, I removed it with no difference (seems logical, it does not do anything in this context).

Comment: The strange thing is, that it only happens with manually backdated posts...

Comment: How and where are you calling `showPosts()`?

Comment: I updated the question accordingly.